Calling markdownit() for a dynamically loaded div


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/13.0.1/markdown-it.min.js" integrity="sha512-SYfDUYPg5xspsG6OOpXU366G8SZsdHOhqk/icdrYJ2E/WKZxPxze7d2HD3AyXpT7U22PZ5y74xRpqZ6A2bJ+kQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var md = window.markdownit();
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('markdown');
  for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    var content = div[i].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByClassName('markdown')[i].innerHTML = md.render(content);
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="markdown">
# h1 Heading
## h2 Heading
### h3 Heading
#### h4 Heading
##### h5 Heading
###### h6 Heading

+ one
+ two
  + two and half
+ three
  + three and half
    + three point seventy five
</div>

</body>
</html>



This is an example of how to call markdownit() for a specific div after the page loads.
On my page, div tags are loaded dynamically after certain user actions. How do I call markdownit() for an emerging div with the id="markdown" attribute?

What do you mean by "div tags are loaded dynamically after certain user actions". Are you gonna use contenteditable="true" or append html using any functions?

For example, the user enters text in the textarea field and presses Enter. After that, a new div tag appears on the page (using javascript), inside which is the text that the user entered. This part is implemented. The question is how to process this text using markdown-it now.

Can you show us the CSS for #markdown please... and thank you.  :)

CSS is not described for it. In the example above, css for div with class="markdown" is also not described.
I am append div tag using insertAdjacentHTML

You indicate that you want to call dynamically loaded div tags with id="markdown", but your code uses <div class="markdown"> ... so, is the CSS #markdown, or .markdown?

This is just an example of the code, the code is not mine. My code uses the id attribute. So I need to implement for #markdown.
But if this is a problem for this task, I will change everything in my code and there will be .markdown

You can achieve this by simply moving your code into a separate function, then call that function whenever user submit new content.
var md = window.markdownit();

function markdownContent() {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('markdown');
  for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    // Check if it is already loaded, if not, add attribute as loaded
    if(div[i].hasAttribute('markdown-loaded')) continue;
    div[i].setAttribute('markdown-loaded', '');

    var content = div[i].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByClassName('markdown')[i].innerHTML = md.render(content);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  markdownContent();
}

Example:


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/13.0.1/markdown-it.min.js" integrity="sha512-SYfDUYPg5xspsG6OOpXU366G8SZsdHOhqk/icdrYJ2E/WKZxPxze7d2HD3AyXpT7U22PZ5y74xRpqZ6A2bJ+kQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <style>
    textarea {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 300px;
      height: 90px;
    }
  </style>

<script>
var md = window.markdownit();

function markdownContent() {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('markdown');
  for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    // Check if it is already loaded, if not, add attribute as loaded
    if(div[i].hasAttribute('markdown-loaded')) continue;
    div[i].setAttribute('markdown-loaded', '');

    var content = div[i].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByClassName('markdown')[i].innerHTML = md.render(content);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  markdownContent();

  const markdownInput = document.querySelector('.markdown-user-input');
  const markdownSubmitButton = document.querySelector('.submit-markdown');
  const markdownOutput = document.querySelector('.dynamic-markdown');

  markdownSubmitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(!markdownInput.value) return void 0;

    markdownOutput.innerHTML = `<div class="markdown">\n${markdownInput.value}\n</div>`;
    markdownContent();
  });

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1 style="color: rgb(104, 104, 104);">Try editing and submit to see dynamic markdown updation.</h1>
<textarea class="markdown-user-input">
# Try Submitting Markdown
## Example of an H2 Heading

- List item
</textarea>
<button class="submit-markdown">Submit Markdown</button>

<h2 style="color: rgb(104, 104, 104);">Rendered Markdown Output</h2>
<div class="dynamic-markdown"></div>

<hr>

<h1 style="color: rgb(104, 104, 104);">Default Markdown Loaded</h1>
<div class="markdown">
  # H1 Heading Example
  ## H2 Heading Example
  ### H3 Heading Example
  #### H4 Heading Example
  ##### H5 Heading Example
  ###### H6 Heading Example
  
  + Item One
  + Item Two
    + Subitem Two
  + Item Three
    + Subitem Three
      + Deeper Subitem
</div>

</body>
</html>




You can reuse your md object and call render on the content you wish and pass the result to the innerHTML of the div you create. Here's an example, where after page load, 100 milliseconds later a new div is created and the process is applied to it successfully.


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/13.0.1/markdown-it.min.js" integrity="sha512-SYfDUYPg5xspsG6OOpXU366G8SZsdHOhqk/icdrYJ2E/WKZxPxze7d2HD3AyXpT7U22PZ5y74xRpqZ6A2bJ+kQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var md = window.markdownit();
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('markdown');
  for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    var content = div[i].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByClassName('markdown')[i].innerHTML = md.render(content);
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.innerHTML += `
<div id="markdown">
# h1 Heading
## h2 Heading
### h3 Heading
#### h4 Heading
##### h5 Heading
###### h6 Heading

+ one
+ two
  + two and half
+ three
  + three and half
    + three point seventy five
</div>`;
  document.getElementById("markdown").innerHTML = md.render(document.getElementById("markdown").innerHTML);
  }, 100);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="markdown">
# h1 Heading
## h2 Heading
### h3 Heading
#### h4 Heading
##### h5 Heading
###### h6 Heading

+ one
+ two
  + two and half
+ three
  + three and half
    + three point seventy five
</div>

</body>
</html>



